# iOS App Store Submission: Does Apple Test Facebook Apps with verified Facebook Accounts?

Tags: ios, facebook, submission

I'm currently in the submission process with Apple.  My app was just rejected, and they've kindly included screenshots.

My App is a Facebook app, and they couldn't login because Facebook is reporting that they are not using a verified Facebook account.

So my question is:  Is Apple testing Facebook apps with 'verified' Facebook accounts, or 'test' Facebook accounts?  If it's the latter, I can flip a switch serverside to fix the issue.

Has anyone run into this during the review process?

Thanks!

(I am not sure if this is NDA or not, but it shouldn't be :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is: No - they use an unverified account (at least in my case).

Comment: Hi, what did you do at the end to dealing with this problem? Could you just create a Facebook account and mentioning the email/pass so they can login with those or they should be able to do it by their own account? tnx

Comment: They use their own facebook account.  They need to be able to log into your app using their own facebook login.  Your Facebook app should not be in sandbox mode at this point.  Also they use an unverified account, meaning that you should give them access even if the 'verified' attribute on the User object you receive from the GraphAPI is 'false'.

Comment: Thanks Shaun for the information. So if the FB app is not in a Sandbox mode and I don't do anything with the 'verified' attribute and simply just get the email address for signup, that would be OK?

Comment: I have one more question. By verified user do you mean the user that is already signed up but not confirmed his email address? The moment you sign up you should confirm the email address. tnx

Comment: Facebook defines this definition, but I think it means that the person has verified their Facebook account with a phone number as well.