# Preparing iOS app submission when using Facebook login

Tags: ios, facebook, submission

I have a native iOS app ready to submit to iTunes Connect. I have some doubts regarding credentials for Facebook, and Apple review process.

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11837840/ios-app-store-submission-does-apple-test-facebook-apps-with-verified-facebook-a) on stackoverflow but the information provided was not enough.

My app uses uses a lot of information depending on your Facebook friends, so I'm a bit concerned also about Apple reviewers finding some views empty if they log in with a test user.

My questions are:

- Do I need to create any test users for my app in order to submit it
  to iTunes Connect?
- Should I include these test user credentials in the app submission data to Apple?
- What are the implications of using non verified users as the question referenced above says?
- Do I need to prevent Apple reviewers that some of the screens might be empty as this is a social app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you would have to create test-accounts for the reviewers to use, and you would have to provide the login in the reviewers comment-section when sending. It would also be smart to fill them with other fake friends before you send them so it's not completely empty, I.E yourself, especially if you don't have any automated events for situations where no one else is using the app.

If your app isn't depending very much on what's actually on the account (I.E friends etc), then sending fake facebook-accounts is probably not necessary, but since you state that friends and their behavior matter, then you should fill up some fake friends with some dummy data, and maybe use it yourself.

This is documented somewhere, and I believe itunesconnect at one point asked me if I had provided user-credentials if I had such an app.

Comment: Thank you very much Rheven! That helps a lot